# What does "TypeError: G must be a 'd' matrix" mean in "cvxpy"?

Tags: python, linear-programming, cvxpy, integer-programming

I am trying to get the solution for the Sudoku binary integer programming (BIP) problem. I am modelling it as:

- Grid: 2D 9x9 list, each with 9 binary variables.
- Constraints: standard sudoku rules
- Objective: Maximize(1)
- Initial values: none, i just want to get a sample solution

Here is the code. The moment is remove the constraint **boolean=True**, there is no error. But how can it work with the boolean constraint. I do not understand the meaning of "TypeError: G must be a 'd' matrix". Any hint will be helpful.

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np


x = [[cp.Variable(9, boolean=True) for j in range(9)] for i in range(9)]
objective = cp.Maximize(1)
constraints = []
cs = constraints
for i in range(9):
  for j in range(9):
    # one value per square
    cs.append(cp.sum(x[i][j]) == 1)
    # unique value every row
    cs.append(cp.sum([x[k][i][j] for k in range(9)]) == 1)
    # unique value every column
    cs.append(cp.sum([x[i][k][j] for k in range(9)]) == 1)
    # unique value every box
    cs.append(cp.sum([x[(i//3)*3+k//3][(i%3)*3+k%3][j] for k in range(9)]) == 1)
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
result = prob.solve()
print("z:", result)

a = [[0 for j in range(9)] for i in range(9)]
for i in range(9):
  for j in range(9):
    for k in range(9):
      if(x[i][j].value[k] > 0):
        a[i][j] = k+1
  print(a[i])
```

Comment: Which solver are you using? Which version of cvxpy? I'm guessing it's trying to use GLPK through cvxopts wrapper and it looks broken (the cvxpy <-> cvxopt wrapper). What happens when enforcing another solver: e.g. ECOS_BB. This will probably lead to other problems, but would give more trust in your model.

Comment: Using `pip3 show cvxpy`, cvxpy: 1.0.28. Using `pip3 show cvxopt`, cvopt: 1.2.4.

Comment: wow! i was struggling with this for hours (new to cvxpy). I changed the if to `if(x[i][j].value[k] > 0.5):` and i get a valid result.

Comment: What does the error "TypeError: G must be a 'd' matrix" mean though? And why did it not work with default solver?

Comment: As i said: probably a broken wrapper. This is your typical cvxopt-error on the edge of glpk, where types start to play a role: d = double.